# Material UI switch inputs not updating on form reset

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hook-form

I'm using `react-hook-form` to build out my form, it is a great tool. However, I can't seem to get the `<Switch />` elements to slide (false/true) based on the return values from redux. **When I click "reset" on my form, all of my inputs reset. My Switch controls do not reset, they remain stuck on their last value regardless of it being possibly reset.** Any thoughts on how to address this?

##### my Switch

```js
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Switch
      size="medium"
      name="familyFriendly"
      defaultChecked={formState.content.isFamilySafe}
      {...register('content.isFamilySafe')}
    />
  }
  label="Family Friendly"
/>
```

##### reset button

```js
   <button
        type="button"
        onClick={() => {
          reset(formState, {
            keepErrors: true,
            keepDirty: true,
            keepIsSubmitted: false,
            keepTouched: false,
            keepIsValid: false,
            keepSubmitCount: false,
          });
        }}
      >
        reset
      </button>
```

##### useForm hook

```
  const formState = useSelector(selectDynamicForm);
  const {
    register,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormInput>({});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

MUI's `<Switch />` component has a slightly different interface for the actual value using `checked` instead of `value`. RHF's `register` returns a `value` property which you spread on the `<Switch />` component, so `checked` is never linked between RHF and the `<Switch />` component.

So you should use RHF's `<Controller />` component to control this external controlled component. Check [here](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#IntegratingControlledInputs) for more information.

```
<FormControlLabel
    control={
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="content.isFamilySafe"
        render={({ field: { value, ...field } }) => (
          <Switch {...field} checked={!!value} size="medium" />
        )}
      />
    }
    label="Family Friendly"
/>
```

You also need to set the `defaultValue` for your input via `useForm` as this is required for `reset` to work properly. From the [docs](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller):

> If your form will invoke `reset` with default values, you will need to
> call useForm with `defaultValues` instead of setting the `defaultValue` on
> individual fields.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - MUI Switch]

Answer (score 1):

I think that `react-hook-form` needs to know that it "watching" a checkbox instead of a text input. Since `<Switch />` is a wrapping component, the ref now targets the div element instead of the input element. However, there is a `inputRef` prop which material-ui forwards to the input element.

```
const { ref, ...rest } = register('content.isFamilySafe');

<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Switch
      size="medium"
      name="familyFriendly"
      defaultChecked={formState.content.isFamilySafe}
      inputRef={ref}
      {...rest}
    />
  }
  label="Family Friendly"
/>
```

Or you could create a wrapper around the register function for `<Switch />` components:

```
function registerSwitch(name) {
  const { ref: inputRef, ...rest } = register(name);
  return { inputRef, ...rest };
}

<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Switch
      size="medium"
      name="familyFriendly"
      defaultChecked={formState.content.isFamilySafe}
      {...registerSwitch('content.isFamilySafe')}
    />
  }
  label="Family Friendly"
/>
```

A third solution is to rewrite the props using a helper function:

```
const fixSwitchProps = ({ ref: inputRef, ...rest }) => ({ inputRef, ...rest });

<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Switch
      size="medium"
      name="familyFriendly"
      defaultChecked={formState.content.isFamilySafe}
      {...fixSwitchProps(registerSwitch('content.isFamilySafe'))}
    />
  }
  label="Family Friendly"
/>
```

Comment: Thank you for these examples! gonna circle back and dig into these in a few days. I tried implementing your second option and I got the following error above the `...args` in `register(...args)`: "A spread argument must either have a tuple type or be passed to a rest parameter."